# Solving the 1D Schrodinger Equation for a Free Particle - Two Different Methods?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

So starting from the time dependent schrodinger equation I perform separation of variables and obtain a time and spatial part. The spatial part is in effect the time independent schrodinger equation.

Since we are dealing with a free particle I can take the time independent equation, set V = 0 and solve.

I can do this successfully to obtain :

$Ae^{+i\sqrt{{2mE}/{\hbar^{2}}}x}+Be^{-i\sqrt{{2mE}/{\hbar^{2}}}x}$

My lecturer has a small section titled :

> Solving for the Free Schrodinger Equation
>
> $$V=0$$
>
> $$\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2}+E\psi=0$$
>
> $$E=\frac{p^2}{2m}$$
>
> $$\psi=Ce^{-{iEt}/{\hbar}+{ipr}/{\hbar}}$$
>
> This is the solution to the free TISE and TDSE.

He seems to be doing the same thing as me initially but he's obtained a different result ?

Also, the first section of his answer :$e^{-{iEt}/{\hbar}}$ is the solution to the time part of the equation (described above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lecturer's answer assumes $p$ can be positive or negative, and your answer assumes $p=\sqrt{2mE}$ is positive. The factor of $\exp{(-iEt/\hbar)}$ is just the time-dependent part of the separated solution.

Comment: So are both valid answers ? Also, when I solve his equation with E = p^2/2m I obtain the solution : Ae^(+ip/hbar)+Be^(-ip/hbar). Why has conveniently ignored one half of this solution ?

Comment: I couldn't tell you why the lecturer chose to write it a certain way, but the solution works for $-p$ just as well as for $+p$. This just corresponds to a particle moving right or moving left. The lecturer's way says there are two solutions, and your way is a superposition of those two. Both are valid.

Comment: So as a final solution if I were to write : $exp(-iEt/\hbar)$*$[A'e^{+ip/\hbar}+B'e^{-ip/\hbar}]$ Would this be also correct ?

Comment: I know I'm really drawing out the issue but I just want to be sure.

Comment: The particle here is moving in both the +x and -x directions, but it's a valid solution to the free particle hamiltonian.

Comment: Oh, I think I see, my lecturer has basically considered the solution for a particle moving the +x direction whilst in my comment I've considered a particle supposedly moving in both +x and -x... Practically speaking my lecturer's solution is more 'correct', I guess ? Does this make sense ?